# I want a conditional query in excel IF 0 =N and anything greater then 0 should be Y

Tags: excel-formula, conditional-statements, excel-2010

**Conditional Statement**

I want a conditional query in excel IF 0 =N and anything greater then 0 should be Y

Answer (score 0):

IF(A1>0,"Y","N") or IF(A1>0,TRUE,FALSE) assuming the value tested is in cell A1 and also that A1 can't be less than 0.